# How to get a constant voltage output from a dc to dc converter?

Tags: power-electronics

I have designed a DC to DC converter on proteus. If I set 4V input voltage, output is 22V at 10kHz, but this output voltage is not constant. How to get a constant voltage output from a DC to DC converter?

EDIT to show the linked circuit:

[image]

Comment: Then you haven't designed what you want - I suggest you link to a picture of your schematic or maybe try adding an LC low pass filter at the output to convert to a smoother dc.

Comment: sorry i cannot share the picture for the schematic, because there is no option given here.

Comment: Post the picture on your favourite share site and add the link to your question - someone with enough reputation will embed it into your question.

Comment: here is the link for the schematic
http://tinypic.com/r/35lb19t/8

Comment: To achieve regulated DC output, you need a control loop that samples the output voltage and drives the switch with an appropriate waveform. This controller could vary the switching frequency, vary the pulse width, or even skip pulses. That's what a Switch-Mode Power Supply (SMPS) controller IC does.

Comment: I have this circuit for dc to dc converter. I need some guidence in order to get a constant voltage output.

Comment: If you want guidance you should read what people tell you. Look at what MarkU said. If you do not understand his advice ask specific questions. Ignoring good advice is unwise.

Comment: @MarkU Which kind of a control loop is necessary to sample the output voltage.

Comment: A control loop consists of modifying the transistor drive waveform (e.g. PWM) based on comparing the output voltage to a voltage reference. You will have to determine what control loop architecture works best for your application. How to compensate the control loop? That's tricky, plan on doing some lab work to tune the actual system. Usually a low-pass filter is used to slow the response time to provide phase margin and prevent unwanted oscillation. Good project for advanced EE student.

Comment: If you're not EE student, and just need the power supply without understand how it works, please consider searching for a ready-made Switching Regulator solution, which would include the controller. Linear Technology, Analog Devices, and Maxim Integrated all make Switching Regulators and offer ready-made designs as evaluation boards. Given the min/max VIN, min/max VOUT, and max IOUT load current, do a parametric search. Good luck...

Answer (score 5):

Your circuit is the bare minimum to produce a boost output voltage - there will always be ripple in this type of circuit and if you want lower ripple try making the output capacitor bigger. If you really want a more stable output than what can be gotten from a bigger output capacitor then your switching frequency of 10kHz would need to rise considerably - typically, modern chips do this and switch at many hundreds of kHz and even a couple of MHz.

Ultimately, if you need a clean and quiet supply to can add a linear voltage regulator after the booster.